# Loop through parallel Layers

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, parallel-processing, photoshop-script

i have a problem with a recursive function. I´ll try to explain as good as possible: 
I have a photoshop-document containing various smart-objects all named: Smart_Objectname.
The Smarts may also contain other Smarts.

I now try to write a function that runs trough the whole document and opens a smart(searches with regex for "Smart"), if it contains another it will open the next one and so on. If the last is reached it starts saving each layer inside the smart named with "Layername.png" as png and closes it again. Then it saves the layers of the Smart before until reaching the root document again.

The "going deeper into smarts part" is already working. But if i have two Smart-objects in the same hierarchy it won´t work and set the wrong Layer as active when going deeper into the first one. I simply can´t find the error, but something seems to be wrong with my code. 
Any help or easier way to do this would be great :)

Here my code so far...maybe a bit complicated:

```
 findSmart(app.activeDocument.layerSets); //call it

function findSmart(layerNode) {    
for (var i=0; i<layerNode.length; i++) {  


   var res = /Smart/;// a reg exp  
     var mat = collectNamesAM(res);// get array of matching layer indexes  
        for( var y = 0; y < mat.length; y++ ){ 
            makeActiveByIndex( mat[y], false );  
            // do something with layer  

            var activeLayer = app.activeDocument.activeLayer;


                //Open smart
                //=======================================================
                var idplacedLayerEditContents = stringIDToTypeID( "placedLayerEditContents" );
                var desc45 = new ActionDescriptor();
                executeAction( idplacedLayerEditContents, desc45, DialogModes.NO );
}//next Smart match if any


    //Go deeper
    findSmart(layerNode[i].layerSets);      


      var len = app.activeDocument.layers.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var layer = app.activeDocument.layers[i];

        //search for all .png Layers to save
        var id = ".png";
        var exist = layer.name.slice(-id.length) == id; // true
        app.activeDocument.activeLayer = layer;
         var activeLayer = app.activeDocument.activeLayer;

        //save pic if .png
        if(exist){

             saveAll();   //just opens each layer in another doc and saves it as png then closes the documents without saving              

        }//end if

    }//end for

  // Close the Smart Object and move to next one
  activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);

}//first smart

}//end function
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. it was just a little mistake with the call of the recursive part(i did it too early) and an if that checks for a smart inside a smart. so the last bit of the code right after the if(exist) thing should be:

```
  if(y == 0){         
    findSmart(layerNode[y].layerSets);
  }

     //Close the Smart Object and move to next one
     activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);

    }//next smart if any
  }//end for
}//end function
```